# break down 3D model to make it lite for gaming engine

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am developing a 3D Game for Android in Unity3D, obviously there are a lot of 3D Models.

I have a very long wall which has some columns. Here's an image

[image: sketchup screen cap]

what would an ideal way to do it.

1. Use this wall as one Mesh
2. Use this wall with grouped meshes
3. Do not use mesh but instead Have model for ONE column, One Grill and one long wall. And by code Instantiate and place columns and grills to get the desired result.

Help me on this, my game has become too heavy... I'm trying to cut down on load of models.

p.s I know instead of 3D Grill I should be using the Texture of this Grill on a 2D Plane(Quad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you read:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/OptimizingGraphicsPerformance.html
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/iphone-PracticalGuide.html
which explains possible bottlenecks and solutions.

You may think your game is quite "light", but it exceeds several of the recommended mobile

guidelines, e.g.: "not more than several hundred draw calls", "not more than 100 thousand

vertices". Also consider non-graphics aspects - are you making use of lots of physics, for

example?

things that may slow down your application : Lots of rigidbodies, collision-tests, forces

etc. requires more calculations, so more taxing on a mobile processor.

from "http://answers.unity3d.com/" forum

Comment: as a general rule... If I put then copies of a 1 meshes in One scene or Instantiate one mesh 10 times. Does that make a difference...